# what is best solution for caching json from server in a web offline application?

Tags: web-applications, pouchdb, service-worker, offline-caching, offlineapps

I building web offline application using angular node.js and oracle as a db.
I using browser service workers for caching stuffs i can caching json from the server with service worker as well. I found another solution for caching these jsons and that is using of pouchdb as frontend database. and for better data syncing i can using couchdb-server in server side of the application as well.
some times i need to run a simple query on my json such as getting one of the records with specific id.
which solution is better for caching these jsons on the browser or is there any other solution for this problem.
note: each json can reach to about 6000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okey to use pouchdb client as client database for even thousands records.